# Why google calendar event is getting created duplicated using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have sheet with data which is to be get used for creating a google calendar event. The process of event creation is in such way that when each cell value  changes from sheet "onEdit" trigger gets called and in script i have certain criteria to get matched before calling a " createEvent()" method. 
Below is snapshot of sheet:
[image]

Criteria is as follows:

```
if(ID_coloumn=="" && start_date_col !="" && end_date_col !="" && status=="Scheduled"){
   //then create even...
}
```

But my problem is at times event are getting created multiple times. Below is screenshot of google calendar's march 15. Here you can see the event name "Sid Event" is duplicate.

[image]

Here is my google apps script code.

```
function main(){

  var RC_value=getRCpositionWithValue();           //Get current row and column number and the value inside that cell
  var day_data=day.getData(RC_value.R,RC_value.C); //Get current row data from sheet (Object)
  Utilities.sleep(100);
  var event_id_col = day_data.range[1];            //Range is the current row's data range horizontally till status
  var status=day_data.range[10];
  var start_date=day_data.range[3];
  var end_date=day_data.range[4];

  if(event_id_col == "" && status == "Scheduled" && end_date != "" && start_date !=""){

    var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("xyz")[0].createEvent(day_data.range[0],start_date,end_date);    

  }else if(event_id_col != ""){ 

    var event_id=day_data.range[1];                            
    if(day_data.range[10]=="Cancelled" || day_data.range[10]=="Bumped"){
      //Delete event

      CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("xyz")[0].getEventById(event_id).deleteEvent();
      day.updateSheetEventId(RC_value.R,day_data.event_id_col,"Deleted");
    }else {
      //Update Event 

      var title=CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("xyz")[0].getEventById(event_id).setTime(day_data.range[3],day_data.range[4]);     
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me out with this. Or if anyone wanna see the code please share you email i will share the sheet and you can debug it. THanks.

Comment: Does it happen that the function get called multiple times consecutively ? In that case you should call spreadsheetApp.flush() to make sure the sheet is up-to-date.

Comment: No, function is not called for multiple time, because I try logging some text before it, and it always shows up at once. But thanks for giving idea of flush thing.

Comment: No multiple call to function as I had tested by logging some text just before function call line, and i always got text printed for single time only.

Comment: Let me guess - you named the function `onEdit`, which automatically creates a simple trigger, and then you also manually created an `on edit` trigger...

Comment: No, I knew that, hence I named the function main(), which get called while changing sheet data. I.e onEdit()

Comment: @tehhowch please can i get your contact info where i can show you the code, im stuck in this since 3 days.

Comment: @SIDMISH Did you resolve your problem?